# How to combine and count two columns in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

My table seems like this;

```
A          B
1          100
1          102
1          105
2          100
2          105
3          100
3          102
```

I want output like this:

```
A          Count(B)
1           3 
1,2         2
1,2,3       3
2           2
3           2
2,3         2
```

How can i do this?

I try to use listagg but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't fully understand the results.  Can you explain how they are calculated?

Comment: Why not also have `"2,3..............2"`?  It's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for my english and i forgot, also have 2,3........2 in output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want to count the number of sets of A that are in the data -- and that your sample results are messed up.

If so:

```
select grp, count(*)
from (select listagg(a, ',') within group (order by a) as grp
      from t
      group by b
     ) b;
```

This gives you the counts for the full combinations present in the data.  The results would be:

```
1,2,3    1
1,3      1
1,2      1
```

You can get the original number of rows by doing:

```
select grp, sum(cnt)
from (select listagg(a, ',') within group (order by a) as grp, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by b
     ) b;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( A, B ) AS
SELECT 1, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 102 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 105 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 105 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 102 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT A,
       COUNT(B)
FROM   (
  SELECT SUBSTR( SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( A, ',' ), 2 ) AS A,
         B
  FROM   table_name
  CONNECT BY PRIOR B = B
  AND    PRIOR A + 1 = A
)
GROUP BY A
ORDER BY A;
```

**Output**:

```
A       COUNT(B)
----- ----------
1              3 
1,2            2 
1,2,3          1 
2              2 
2,3            1 
3              2
```